# A Dart app won't show anything in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dart

Years ago I posted a question: [Chrome 39 renders a compiled Dart app as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586117/chrome-39-renders-a-compiled-dart-app-as-blank), mentioned that Chrome shows blank page for a compiled Dart JS, while Firefox shows it correctly. Both works fine when accessed remotely.

Today, I tried to re-pick up my Dart programming but found the problem is reversed: Chrome shows the compiled JS fine, while FX fails, when accessed locally. FX won't show the compiled JS when accessed remotely.

Chrome can run the Dart with **localhost:8080** under `pub serve`, but Fx can't either.

Any helpful hints?

Chrome: 46.0 64bit
Firefox: 41.0

[image]

Comment: Can you publish the project (reduced to a minimal reproducible example) to GitHub?

Comment: Do you get any error message in the browser console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It is a simple polymer web project created with stagehand web-polymer, then pub get, pub serve.

Comment: In Fx, the error msg in console look like the newly inserted screen shot above in my post.

Comment: Now, you only need to provide some source of your application so we are able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are you using Polymer?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, I am.

Comment: If you would provide the project as GitHub repo it would probably be easy to figure out. Without an repo case it's just wild unguided guessing.